# Email recipient name verification

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

There is a tool in outlook that notifies a sender about possible missing attachments as they click the send button.  This tool seems to search the body of the email for keywords like "attachment" and then check to see if anything is attached to the email.  If not, the notification then pops up.

I'm looking for something similar but a bit more advanced.  I would like a similar notification pop-up to appear when the body of my email does not contain neither the first name nor the last name of my recipient(s).

**EDIT / UPDATE**

I have eventually created my own VBA code to solve this problem, based on FaneDuru's answer.  *Please consider unclosing this question.*

**Note:** my code searches for either the first, middle(s) or last name of each one of the recipients, but only on the first two lines of the body of the email.
If any one of these searches is successful (i.e. if the name is found on the first 2 lines), then the check is successful and the email can be sent, otherwise the sender is notified.

When the recipient's email address is not in the address book of the sender, the programme does other similar things that can be easily seen in the code.

Please feel free to suggest improvements.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
       Dim myMail As MailItem, recip As Recipient, strNoRef As String, msg As VbMsgBoxResult, msge As VbMsgBoxResult, noEntry As String
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim j As Integer
       Dim Lines() As String
       Dim fLines As String
       i = 0
       j = 0
       Set myMail = Item
       Lines = Split(myMail.Body, vbCrLf, 4)
       fLines = Lines(0) & Lines(1) & Lines(2)
       For Each recip In myMail.Recipients
           If recip.Address <> recip.AddressEntry Then
               i = i + 1
               If Not NameExists(recip.AddressEntry, fLines) Then
                   j = j + 1
                   strNoRef = strNoRef & recip.AddressEntry & vbCrLf
               End If
           End If
       Next

       For Each recip In myMail.Recipients
           If Not recip.Address <> recip.AddressEntry Then
               noEntry = noEntry & recip.AddressEntry & vbCrLf
           End If
       Next

       If j = i And noEntry = "" Then
           msg = MsgBox("This mail does not contain a reference to anyone of the following:" & vbCrLf & _
           vbCrLf & strNoRef & vbCrLf & _
           "To send the mail anyway, please press ""Yes"".", vbYesNo, "Send the mail?")
           If msg <> vbYes Then Cancel = True
       End If

       If j = i And noEntry <> "" Then
           msg = MsgBox("This mail does not contain a reference to anyone of the following:" & vbCrLf & _
           vbCrLf & strNoRef & vbCrLf & _
           "And the following recipients are not in the address book:" & vbCrLf & _
           vbCrLf & noEntry & vbCrLf & _
           "To send the mail anyway, please press ""Yes"".", vbYesNo, "Send the mail?")
           If msg <> vbYes Then Cancel = True
       End If
                                
       If noEntry <> "" And j < i Then
           msge = MsgBox("The following recipients are not in the address book:" & vbCrLf & _
           vbCrLf & noEntry & vbCrLf & "So, the email was not sent." & vbCrLf & _
           "To send it, please press ""Yes"".", vbYesNo, "Send the mail?")
           If msge <> vbYes Then Cancel = True
       End If
       
       If noEntry = "" And j < i Then
           Cancel = False
       End If
       
   End If
End Sub

Function NameExists(strName As String, strBody As String) As Boolean
   Dim arrName, El
   arrName = Split(strName, " ")
   For Each El In arrName
        If InStr(1, strBody, El, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            NameExists = True: Exit Function
        End If
   Next El
End Function
```

Comment: Not so clear what you want. If something similar to the mentioned tool, an event must be triggered when you try sending the mail. I think, it can be done. An eloquent message to be sent and sending to be cancelled . But I cannot understand the last part regarding "verification in a given outlook folder"... The mail items from a specific folder can be enumerated and event their body can be extracted and searched against a string, but which to be the use of such an approach? Besides all that, please show us what you tried by your own, even if it does not work as you need. At least, some research

Comment: The last paragraph is there as a simpler alternative, in case the main request proves too tedious/complicated.  Sent emails are configured to stay in my Outbox for 5 minutes before they delivered to the recipients.  The use of the alternative solution would then be to get notified about the missing recipient name in the body before the email is sent.  This in turn would provide a further check to prevent senders from emailing the wrong contact.  I can understand a VBA code, and perform some edits, but I haven't studied VBA, so I can't write anything from scratch.

Comment: OK. I will design a piece of code able to trigger the `Sent` event, searching for (all) recipients name(s) in the mail body and send a message containing the ones not being mentioned. It will also ask if you want allowing it to be sent as it is...

Comment: @FaneDuru  That would be quite helpful.  Thanks

Comment: Please, test the solution I posted. If something not clear enough, do  not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: @FaneDuru Awesome code, thanks. _ Feedback: It works as intended. In case of a contact name with more than one space, e.g. Chris M. Smith, it will accept either one of the 3 strings (Chris, M. and Smith). _ One question: Currently, when a recipient can't be found, e.g. because the email address is not in the contact list of the sender, the macro ignores that recipient in the check (still, it does check all the other recipients). _ Would it be possible to get a second notification in those cases, simply to inform that the recipient in question was not part of the check?

Comment: @FaneDuru  Why was the question closed?  Especially after it had received a useful answer?

Comment: There are rules to obey when place an answer. You must prove that made some researches by your own... A piece of code would also help.

Comment: @FaneDuru  Hi again, I have made some significant changes to the programme.  Please check this in the edit made to my question above.  Feel free to let me know what you think, and also to vote to reopen the question, please if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: I voted to be reopened (some time ago) but it needs more such votes and people verry rarely come back to check a closed question... That's why you must learn to place an eligible question, respecting all the community rules. About the code modifications, this is the way. You will learn by trying. From logical point of view, the last condition (`If noEntry = "" And j < i Then`) looks a little strange. On my taste to make the variable `False` after you wanted it `True` looks unusual, but here we do not comment the operational needs. You must know better what is in the user advantage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you try explaining, please proceed in the next way:

1. Change Outlook security settings to make it open with `Macro Enabled`:

`File - Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings... - Macro Settings` and choose `Notifications for all Macros`, or `Enable All Macros (not recommended...`. Press 'OK', of course...

Close and reopen Outlook, choosing `Enable Macros`!

2. Press `F11` in order to access VBE (Visual Basic for Applications) window. In its left pane you will see `Project1 (VBAProject.OTM)`.

Expand `Microsoft Outlook Objects` and double click on `ThisOutlookSession`.

3. In the opening window (to the right side), please copy the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
       Dim myMail As MailItem, recip As Recipient, strNoRef As String, msg As VbMsgBoxResult, noEntry As String
       Set myMail = Item                          'just to benefit of intellisense suggestions...
        For Each recip In myMail.Recipients   'iterate between mail recipients
            If recip.Address <> recip.AddressEntry Then 'if the address has a name (not only xxx@domain.com):
                If Not NameExists(recip.AddressEntry, myMail.Body) Then 'check if one of its names (first or last) exists
                    strNoRef = strNoRef & recip.AddressEntry & vbCrLf      'if not, build a string to be used in the message
                End If
            Else
                noEntry = noEntry & recip.AddressEntry & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
        
        If noEntry <> "" Then
            MsgBox "The following recipients are not in the address book:" & vbCrLf & _
                   vbCrLf & noEntry
        End If
        If strNoRef <> "" Then
            msg = MsgBox("The mail you try sending does not contain a reference to" & vbCrLf & _
                vbCrLf & strNoRef & vbCrLf & "and it cannot be sent..." & vbCrLf & _
                "To send it as it is, please press ""Yes"".", vbYesNo, "Send the mail?")
            If msg <> vbYes Then Cancel = True 'if not pressing "Yes", the sending will be cancelled
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function NameExists(strName As String, strBody As String) As Boolean
   Dim arrName, El
   arrName = Split(strName, " ")
   For Each El In arrName
        If InStr(1, strBody, El, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            NameExists = True: Exit Function
        End If
   Next El
End Function
```

It would be good to press `Save` on the VBE `Standard` toolbar. I thing `Ctrl + S` will also work...

Try playing with mails and send some feedback...

Comment: Awesome code, thanks.
_
Feedback:
It works as intended. 
In case of a contact name with more than one space, e.g.  Chris M. Smith, it will accept either one of the 3 strings (Chris, M. and Smith).
 _
One question:
Currently, when a recipient can't be found, e.g. because the email address is not in the contact list of the sender, the macro ignores that recipient in the check (still, it does check all the other recipients).
_
Would it be possible to get a second notification in those cases, simply to inform that the recipient in question was not part of the check?

Comment: @Stephen Glad I could help!. For more names, the code checks **each of them**. Now, when the recipient is  not found in the address book, it skips it. Here: `recip.Address <> recip.AddressEntry`. All the others are checked. Yes, it is possible, but you risk to receive a lot of notifications. I will try selecting all such cases and show them in a message, without cancelling the sending. Would be that what you need? If not, how would you like it to behave?

Comment: Yes, what you described would be perfect!

Comment: @Stephen Please, check the adapted version and send some feedback.

Comment: Great! I made a slight change to give the option to either cancel or send the email when recipient is not in the address book. It works really well.  Here is the update :

'''
        If noEntry <> "" Then
            msge = MsgBox("The following recipients are not in the address book:" & vbCrLf & _
                vbCrLf & noEntry & vbCrLf & "So, the email was not sent..." & vbCrLf & _
                "To send it anyway, please press ""Yes"".", vbYesNo, "Send the mail?")
            If msge <> vbYes Then Cancel = True
'''

I had to define msge first as a VbMsgBoxResult.

Comment: @Stephen OK, great... Anyhow, it should be time to learn some VBA, since you intend to use it... :)

Comment: Yes, definitely will :-)  I didn't think I could find such a quick solution with only a half a page long VBA code.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Stephen Welcome! I do not use VBA in Outlook (for myself). I only take challenges looking interesting and try supplying a solution. It is good to keep the brain warm... :)